# php transformToXML method ignores sort

Tags: php, sorting, xslt

I´m searching for days but can´t find a solution. I use php´s XSLTProcessor method to output a xml-file transformed by a xsl-file.

Everything works perfect except the sort function in the xsl-file.

(For testing I´ve added the xsl-file-path in the xml-file and opened it directly in Firefox: Result is well sorted by @name Attribute - but via php-transform it isn´t)

Here is a Code Snippet:

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <clients>
    <c name="A_client" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="B_client" id="2" generated="2013-04-25" p_count="0"/>
    <c name="C_client" id="3" generated="2013-04-26 23:35" p_count="0"/>
  </clients>
</user>
```

XSL FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="user">
    <ul class="topiclist">
      <xsl:for-each select="clients/c">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <li class="round_corner_3"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PHP Function

```
function xsl_transform_xml($xsl_file, $xml_file) {
  $xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xslDoc -> load($xsl_file);

  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlDoc -> load($xml_file);

  $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
  $proc -> importStylesheet($xslDoc);
  return $proc -> transformToXML($xmlDoc);
}
```

---

yes that´s right - but when the xml code gets more detailed the output is ordered in a strange way.

using this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <clients>
    <c name="C_client" id="3" generated="2013-04-26 23:35" p_count="0"/>    
    <c name="B_client" id="2" generated="2013-04-25" p_count="0"/>
    <c name="cone" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="c_two" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="cthree" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="Hoff" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="Nimu" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="Xing" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
    <c name="Whatever" id="1" generated="2013-04-17" p_count="1"/>
  </clients>
</user>
```

result with php processing is:

```
B_client
C_client
Hoff
Nimu
Whatever
Xing
c_two
cone
cthree
```

and when xml file is directly opened in browser (xsl file-path added)

```
B_client
C_client
c_two
cone
cthree
Hoff
Nimu
Whatever
Xing
```

(edit)

don´t know if it helps to post my libxslt Version but if so here it is:
1.1.24

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With libxslt 1.1.25, you can use the `lang` attribute of `xsl:sort` which should do what you want on most operating systems.

With libxslt 1.1.24, you should sort on a lowercased version of the string. Unfortunately, there's no `lower-case` function in XPath 1.0. All you can do is to use `translate` and specify the set of characters manually. With pure ASCII, the following works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="user">
    <ul class="topiclist">
      <xsl:for-each select="clients/c">
        <xsl:sort select="translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" lang="de"/>
        <li class="round_corner_3"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```